# Visual Studio 2010 and windows SDK 7.0a compilation error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I am new to windows development world. I am having Visual Studio 2010 and windows SDK 7.0a installed on my machine. Any win32 application (even the skeleton generated using the wizard) is giving me this compilation error repeated hundreds of times:

---

*2>  Note: including file:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdio.h*
*2>  Note: including file:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h*
*2>  Note: including file:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\swprintf.inl*
*2>  Note: including file:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\Windows.h*
*2>  Note: including file:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\sdkddkver.h*
*2>  Note: including file:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\excpt.h*
*2>  Note: including file:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h*
*2>  Note: including file:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdarg.h*
*2>  Note: including file:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\windef.h*
*2>  Note: including file:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h*
*2>  Note: including file:     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ctype.h*
*2>  Note: including file:      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h*
*2>  Note: including file:     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\specstrings.h*
*2>  Note: including file:      c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\sal_supp.h*
*2>  Note: including file:      c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\specstrings_supp.h*
*2>  Note: including file:      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\specstrings_strict.h*
*2>  Note: including file:       C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\specstrings_undef.h*
*2>  Note: including file:      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\driverspecs.h*
*2>  Note: including file:       c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\sdv_driverspecs.h*
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\driverspecs.h(356): **error C3861: 'SAL_functionClass': identifier not found**
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\driverspecs.h(356): **error C2059: syntax error : ')'**
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\driverspecs.h(374): **error C2144: syntax error : 'char' should be preceded by ')'**
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\driverspecs.h(374): **error C3861: 'SAL_acquire': identifier not found**

---

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Also I have language extensions enabled

Comment: What kind of application? Win32 API or MFC?

Comment: I need to work on a Win32 API with WinForms GUI but even win32 skeleton generated by VC++ is giving same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at your VS include paths.  If you installed more SDKS (ie, Windows 7.1  or others) then the order may have gotten screwed up.  Or perhaps you modified the paths to add some of your own.

Go to Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories.  Mine looks like this:

**Include Directories =**`$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;`

I'd suggest making them look like the default and seeing if you still have the problem.  You may have to fix your Library Directories if it doesn't link after it compiles.  Mine looks like this:

**Library Directories =**`$(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(WindowsSdkDir)lib;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\lib`