# VS 2010 Compile error in SDK include headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, header-files

I had one problem when compiling code with VS2010. I got the following 100+ errors with the SDK headers. When I compiled the exact same code with VS2013 and V120, it worked fine. 
I found similar problem on following link but it didn't work. 
[[Visual Studio 2010 and windows SDK 7.0a compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000342/visual-studio-2010-and-windows-sdk-7-0a-compilation-error])

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oaidl.h(5472): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oaidl.h(5497): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oaidl.h(5507): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oaidl.h(5525): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oaidl.h(5544): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oaidl.h(5569): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\oaidl.h(5579): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(303): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_pchBuf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(303): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(303): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(306): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_pszFound'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(306): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(306): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(307): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_pszExpected'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(307): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(307): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(410): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(535): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(596): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(599): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\msxml.h(602): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BSTR'
```

For Jonathan's question, the include part in the main cpp is as the following:

```
// Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include <math.h>
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <afx.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>
#include <direct.h>
// insert specific include here
#include "recordSet.h"
#define  roundX(x)  ( floor(100.0 * x + 0.49 )) / 100  ;
#include "OutputAccumulator.h"
using namespace std;
```

Here is the code of stdfax.h:

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4786) 

#if !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__25F9CFE5_5C52_11D5_98E7_000255667102__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_STDAFX_H__25F9CFE5_5C52_11D5_98E7_000255667102__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000

#define VC_EXTRALEAN        // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

#include <afx.h>
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
#include <afxdao.h>         // MFC DAO database classes
#include <afxdtctl.h>       // MFC support for Internet Explorer 4 Common Controls
#ifndef _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT
#include <afxcmn.h>         // MFC support for Windows Common Controls
#endif // _AFX_NO_AFXCMN_SUPPORT

#include <iostream>


#define     VERY_SMALL_VALUE    0.0000001

// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here

//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

#endif // !defined(AFX_STDAFX_H__25F9CFE5_5C52_11D5_98E7_000255667102__INCLUDED_)
```

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Please add the code where you include the headers. Without it we can only guess.

Comment: I think the program includes headers thru the Configuration properties. A snapshot is added to original post. My problem is that the code can compile w/t VS2013 but not VS2010.

Comment: Hey sorry I wasn't able to upload a pic. The headers are include under property->Configuration Properties->VC++->Include Directories

Comment: There are a dozen possibilities here and we have no way of guessing what it might be given the information you've provided.

Comment: That setting just specifies the directories include files can be found in, but the actual files your project includes come from the `#include ...` lines either at the top of your .cpp files or in `stdafx.h`.

Comment: Yea. Thanks for the info. I attached the project code.

Comment: You could check that that file (MsXml.h) hasn't become corrupt for some reason - line 307 (on my machine) is `BSTR _pszExpected;`, but there are `BSTR` declarations just above this line, so it can't be BSTR not being defined.

Comment: Now that you have updated the errors, it appears that BSTR is not defined. Try compiling to a preprocessed file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. This will produce a .i file in your debug directory instead of producing an obj file. You should look to see if BSTR is typedefed somewhere in this file. It should be done by wtypes.h

Comment: You don't seem to be including `<windows.h>`. Try that.

Comment: I included <windows.h>. There was no miracle :( I felt really wired as exactly same code worked for VS2013 but failed for VS2010. It seemed like some settings issue.

Comment: Dear all, I installed VS2010 on another computer and it all worked fine. Looks like different versions of VS messed up my computer and I was still wondering why. Please let me know if you find out the reason. Thanks.